# Not generating (or receiving?) All the notifications I expect

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

I wrote s simple app to receive BLE advertisements and generate a Notification for each one received. The problem is I am not seeing a notification for every BLE packet I receive.

The device settings directly affect what is displayed. This is what I have set on my iPhone:

- iOS 12.4.1
- General->Notifications->app name->
- Allow Notifications:On
- Alerts: Lock, Notification Center & Banners
- Banner Style: Temporary
- Show Previews: Always
- Grouping: Off

App Delegate:

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    guard let serviceData = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataServiceData"] as? [CBUUID:Data] else {
      return
    }

    // get the message-specific payload
    guard let payload = serviceData[CBUUID(string: "FDF4")] else {
      return
    }

    // Try to parse this advertisement. 
    let parseResults = self.parsingService.parseData(payload)

    // validate this packet. 
    if self.parsingService.isParseError(parseResults: parseResults, rawBytes: payload.hexEncodedString()) {
      return
    }

    // the packet looks good. Convert it to our internal format
    let newPacket = OEMRecord(parseApiResults: parseResults)

    // filter out a specific message type to reduce chatter
    if (newPacket.getMsgTypeAsInt() == kMessageTypeToListenFor) {
      let serialNumber = newPacket.serialNo
      if (serialNumber == kSerialNumberToListenFor) {

        // we found the device we want!
        let msg = "Found tracker: \(serialNumber)"
        self.logMessage(msg: msg)

        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            // we have received a tracker pkt. Tell the entire app (i.e. pass msg to ViewController)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(didReceiveDesiredTracker), object: self, userInfo: ["text": msg])
         }
      }
    }
}
```

View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Request permission to send notifications
    notificationCenter.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(processReceiveDesiredTrackerNotification(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: didReceiveDesiredTracker),
                                           object: nil)
}

// log the incoming BLE msgs to the console & the GUI
@objc func processReceiveDesiredTrackerNotification (notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let payload = notification.userInfo else { return }     // sanity chk - probably unnecesary

    guard let msg = payload["text"] as? String  else { return }    // ensure we have a payload to display

    // log to console & GUI
    self.logMessage(msg: msg)

    // generate a Local Notification
    self.scheduleNotification(msg: msg)
}


// show a (Local) Notification for the pkt just received
private func scheduleNotification(msg: String) {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "ALARM #\(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)"
    content.body = "\(msg) #\(UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber)"
    content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber as NSNumber // keep running count of # of pkts received

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "BLEScannerNotification", content: content, trigger: nil)
        notificationCenter.add(request)
}
```

The BLE packets arrive in bursts of 5-7 full packets per burst. The packets within a burst are spaced approx. 0.5 secs apart. Each burst is spaced minutes apart.

1) In the console, I see a log message forever packet received.

2) However, I only get 1 Notification for each burst. It seems that NotificationCenter handles the 1st notification and disregards (or rolls up) the remaining notifications in each burst.

What am I missing?